# Mostrar un dato de Json en un textview android

Tags: java, android

tengo esa duda de como pasar un campo del json "nombre" a un text view, ya obtengo los datos del json con el id correspondiente, y me los muestra todos , pero lo que quiero es mandar a un textview el nombre, a otro la descripcion y asi sucesivamente.
Este es mi codigo y el json arrojado con algun id ingresado es este
"cerveza": {
"id": 5,
"nombre": "Indio",
"descripcion": "Obscura 355ml",
"precio": "25",
"provedor_id": "2"
}

```
 public void Mostar(){
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
        String id = id_cerveza.getText().toString().trim();

        String url = "http://10.0.0.12/ProyectoFinal/public/api/cervezas/"+id;
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, object, new com.android.volley.Response.Listener<JSONObject>(){
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                tvNombre.setText(response.toString());


            }
        }, new com.android.volley.Response.ErrorListener(){
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                tvNombre.setText(error.toString());
            }
        });
        requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Si tu json tiene esta estructura

```
{
  "cerveza": {
    "id": 5,
    "nombre": "Indio",
    ...
  }
}
```

para acceder a `nombre` primero debes acceder a `cerveza`.

La forma de acceder a un elemento es siempre la misma: usar el método get del tipo que corresponda. `cerveza` es un objeto json, entonces debes usar el método `getJSONObject()`. Desde ahí quieres acceder a `nombre` que es una string, entonces usas el método `getString()`

```
public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
    try {
        JSONObject cerveza = response.getJSONObject("cerveza");
        String nombre = cerveza.getString("nombre");
        tvNombre.setText(nombre);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```